# Big files aren't uploading through my js plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis-express, filesize

I made a small (jQuery + ajax + backend) file uploading plugin. When I was testing this plugin I noticed that some files are not being uploaded to my server (they give me an exception). Then, I realised that the problem is in their sizes: smaller ones are going well, but the bigger ones not. Then I made a junk txt file constisting of symbols, in order to count what is the filesize quota. So, files before 4 194 116 b passes, files from 4 194 117 not.

I don't know whether it is a js's problem, or ajax's problem, or maybe even IIS and Visual Studio. What am I supposed to do to check where is the problem or any bandwidth options?

> **TL;DR: Files bigger than 4194116 bytes are not being uploaded by js.**

**Update 1:** I know about request-size settings in web.config. It is set properly:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="153600" executionTimeout="60" /><!--150MB (in kbytes) & 60s timeout-->
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" /> <!--150MB (in bytes)-->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Could the problem be in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539/6184866 ?
If so, how to change `maxJsonLength`? I am not shure I need to do this in the controller, cause controller's setting based on `web.config` of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem. I just set the limitations in `View`'s `Web.config` but it should be in main `Web.config` in the root.